# Jekyll default page

Tags: jekyll

How can I change the default starting page? Currently, index.html is always the index of posts.

I like to show the content of my current /about page on index.html and like to have an /articles link to the index of posts instead.

Is copy pasting /about/index.html's content into /index.html the only solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This not really a Jekyll problem, it's more an Information Architecture one.

Your page hierachy is like this :

```
|-index.html
|-articles.html
|-...
```

Just add the content you want in `index.html` or `index.md`, if you want to write it in markdown.

Create an `article.html` or `md` page and just copy the actual content of index.html in it.

Finally if you want to reach your articles page at `/articles/`, just add `permalink: articles/` in the front matter. Otherwise, by default it will be reached at `articles.html`.

Comment: Great, that one helped  :)!

Comment: @Christopher How could it possibly help?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [gem 'jekyll-redirect-from'](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) in `jekyll` to set different homepage than index.html and also customize output URL of any xxxx.html.

Add this line to your project's `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'jekyll-redirect-from'
```

And then execute in terminal:

```
bundle
```

Once it's installed into your environment, add it to your `_config.yml`:

```
plugins:
  - jekyll-redirect-from
```

---

Now, To set `about.html` as homepage:
Add it at start of `about.html`:

```
---
permalink: /
redirect_from:
  - /about
---
```

As a result, `www.website.com/about` will redirect to `www.website.com` and content of `about.html` will be shown.

Comment: If anyone wonders, this gem uses HTTP-REFRESH meta tag to perform redirect ( https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from#how-it-works )